# Pager in asp.net GridView disappears with bootstrap styling?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, pagination, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a asp.net GridView that I am trying to give the pager a style with bootstrap.  If I use:

`<PagerStyle CssClass="pagination" />`, I don't get any intellisense from bootstrap and no styling

`<PagerTemplate><div class="pagination"/></PagerTemplate>` hides the page numbers

I have tried showing the Pager on RowDataBound, but the pager is not still null during this.

Why is the pager hidden when I use the PagerTemplate?

The html generated for the pager is:

```
<tr>
<td colspan="5">
<div class="pagination"></div>
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Try to look here, looks like almost the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928007/custom-pagertemplate

Comment: This question has already an answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22420602/simple-script-to-apply-bootstrap-pagination-style-in-asp-net-gridview